# How do I cut transparent bits out of an otherwise opaque canvas in WPF?

Tags: wpf, drawing, transparency

I have a drawing in WPF, where I set up a canvas, with a background colour and then draw lots of things over that.  Now I want to make cuttouts, i.e. have transparent regions in fairly arbitrary shapes.  My approach is to use a `VisualBrush` as an opacity mask.

Here is a simplified  version of the work in progress

```
<Canvas Background="LightGray" Width="{Binding SizeX}" Height="{Binding SizeY}">
     <Canvas.OpacityMask>
     <VisualBrush 
        VIEWPORT / TILING VOODO HERE
     >
         <VisualBrush.Visual>
             <Canvas Background="#ffffffff" Width="{Binding SizeX}" Height="{Binding SizeY}">
                      DRAW CUTTOUTS HERE. 
                      If I got the Viewport/tiling voodoo right I should
                      just use the same coordinate system as for visible things.
             </Canvas>
         </VisualBrush.Visual>
     </VisualBrush>
     </Canvas.OpacityMask>

    DRAW VISIBLE THINGS HERE
</Canvas>
```

But I am running afoul of retained-mode drawing.  The idea was to fill the background alpha channel with `#ff` so that things are opaque by default, and then have transparent cuttouts.  But of course what that evaluates to is transparent shapes on top of a completely opaque background, and thus no cuttouts.

So how do I get my cuttouts?

Answer (score 0):

here you go

I placed a inner canvas to host your content and used the same canvas as the visual for visual brush which will be used for the opacity mask for outer canvas. this will enable you to cut the outer canvas based on the content in inner canvas

```
<Canvas x:Name="outer" Background="Green" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Canvas x:Name="inner" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=outer}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=outer}">
        <!--your arbitery content here-->
        <Ellipse Width="20" Height="10" Fill="Gray" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=inner}" 
                     ViewportUnits="Absolute" ViewboxUnits="Absolute"
                     Viewbox="0,0,100,100" Viewport="0,0,100,100"/>
        <!--you may need to write conveter class for conversion from SizeX & SizeY to Viewbox & Viewport-->
    </Canvas.OpacityMask>
</Canvas>
```

all what is hard-coded in the example is the Viewbox & Viewport numbers (also hard-coded the width and height of outer canvas to match the numbers), you may write a converter for the same to bind with SizeX & SizeY as all the properties in visual brush need to be accurate in order to map it correctly

**note** do not apply background to inner canvas

**Update**

as discussed if you want to cutout the background of the canvas instead of showing the shapes here is the sample, also added trigger to disable the opacity mask if there are no shapes to cut out

```
<Canvas Background="Green">
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Canvas x:Key="maskVisual">
                    <!--your arbitery content here-->
                    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="10" Fill="Gray" 
                             Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource maskVisual}"
                                 ViewportUnits="Absolute" ViewboxUnits="Absolute"
                                 Viewbox="0,0,100,100" Viewport="0,0,100,100"/>
                    <!--you may need to write conveter class for conversion from SizeX & SizeY to Viewbox & Viewport-->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Children.Count, Source={StaticResource maskVisual}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```

1 point to notice is that, since canvas do not clip by default you may not require to set the width and height explicitly

Comment: Won't this make the green background disappear?  If I understand correctly, `outer` will be transparent wherever you have not drawn anything into `inner`.  Or does the background ignore the opacity mask?

Comment: so you just want to see the cutout with original background? secondly if there is no element then outer will be completely transparent. however this can be handled via trigger.

Comment: I'm going to try this out when I get time, then maybe I will understand it and know whether to accept your answer.

Comment: take your time, happy coding :)